# 'True' and 'False' in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I tried running this piece of code:

```
path = '/bla/bla/bla'

if path is True:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

And it prints **False**. I thought Python treats anything with value as **True**. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

From *[6.11. Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)*:

> > In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

The key phrasing here that I think you are misunderstanding is "interpreted as false" or "interpreted as true".  This does not mean that any of those values are identical to True or False, or even equal to True or False.

The expression `'/bla/bla/bla'` will be treated as true where a Boolean expression is expected (like in an `if` statement), but the expressions `'/bla/bla/bla' is True` and `'/bla/bla/bla' == True` will evaluate to False for the reasons in Ignacio's answer.

Comment: +1 I think this is the underlaying misunderstanding. Maybe it helps to know that there is a `bool` function that "interprets" a value as a boolean. You could say this function is called implicitly in every `if` (which is probably not true in a technical sense, but at least adding it never changes the behavior of a if statement).

Answer (score 106):

`is` compares identity. A string will never be identical to a not-string.

`==` is equality. But a string will never be equal to either `True` or `False`.

You want neither.

```
path = '/bla/bla/bla'

if path:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

Answer (score 5):

While the other posters addressed why `is True` does what it does, I wanted to respond to this part of your post:

> I thought Python treats anything with value as True. Why is this happening?

Coming from Java, I got tripped up by this, too. Python does not treat anything with a value as `True`. Witness:

```
if 0:
    print("Won't get here")
```

This will print nothing because 0 is treated as `False`. In fact, zero of any numeric type evaluates to `False`. They also made `decimal` work the way you'd expect:

```
from decimal import *
from fractions import *

if 0 or 0.0 or 0j or Decimal(0) or Fraction(0, 1):
    print("Won't get here")
```

Here are the other value which evaluate to `False`:

```
if None or False or '' or () or [] or {} or set() or range(0):
    print("Won't get here")
```

Sources:

1. *[Python Truth Value Testing is Awesome](https://medium.com/@dawran6/python-truth-value-testing-is-awesome-dae6c23cc1c2)*
2. *[Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)* (in *Built-in Types*)