# Python program to count the values associated with key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def wut(data):
    s = 0
    for dic in data:
        for i,value in dic.items():
            if value == "True":
                s += 1
    return s

data = [{'id': 1, 'success': True, 'name': 'Lary'},
        {'id': 2, 'success': False, 'name': 'Rabi'}, 
        {'id': 3, 'success': True, 'name': 'Alex'}]
wutewa = data
print wut(wutewa)
```

Hello, the code above when fed into python tutor doesn't move forward with checking if `value=="True"` , I'm not sure where I went wrong. I know I could use `sum` function but I have this thing that if I try and use as much as data structures as possible I'll be able to develop a way of thinking to code.

Answer (score 4):

Should be `value == True` not `value == "True"`

Or, as [Jean-François Fabre points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077030/python-program-to-count-the-values-associated-with-key-in-a-dictionary#comment79115386_46077062), simply:

```
if value:
     s += 1
```

Comment: I was about to comment that but no, you can't do that here, as numbers and non-empty strings still evaluate to `True`. **EDIT:** To add context, the missing comment was *"or just use `if value`"*.

Comment: I just deleted my comment. Shouldn't it be `value is True` in that case? (singleton, more pythonic, yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591125/is-it-safe-to-replace-with-is-to-compare-boolean-values)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre interesting question. Apparently it has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119709/true-and-false-in-python)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm not sure, I know `is` is considered most idomatic for `None` checks, but  for booleans you might miss different identity objects like `numpy.True_` or `scipy.True_`

Comment: I'm not sure that OP wants `1==True`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing to string `"True"` instead of boolean `True`, you can also use an expression with built in `sum()` to do what you want in a more pythonic way as the following:

```
def wut(data):
    return sum(1 for dic in data for v in dic.values() if v is True)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to find how many items are "truthy" values is to use list comprehension:

```
data = [{'id': 1, 'success': True, 'name': 'Lary'},
    {'id': 2, 'success': False, 'name': 'Rabi'}, 
    {'id': 3, 'success': True, 'name': 'Alex'}]

def wut(d):
   return sum(sum(bool(b) for b in i.values()) for i in d)

print(wut(data))
```

Output:

```
8
```